# How do I speed up MG995 servo motor using PCA9685 motor driver?

Tags: pi-3, driver, servo

I am using PCA9685 to drive a MG995 servo motor. I am using the following code to control the servo motor.

```
import time,Adafruit_PCA9685

def elbow():
    pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
    pwm.set_pwm_freq(50)
    down=565
    up=145
    pin=3

    for i in range(up,down,1):
        pwm.set_pwm(pin,0,i)
        time.sleep(0.001)
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(down,up,-1):
        pwm.set_pwm(pin,0,i)
        time.sleep(0.001)

if __name__=='__main__':
   elbow()
```

The above code works fine but the servo motor rotates very slowly. I have double checked the power requirements of the PCA9685 driver. I am supplying 5V,2A to the V+ pin of the driver and 3.3V( from the Raspberry Pi ) to the Vcc pin of the driver as specified. I have plugged in the servo motor in the Pin number 3 of the PCA driver. Inspite of the correct voltage supply, the motor rotates very slowly. I have tried to change the value of the frequency, `pwm.set_pwm_freq(50)` between the range 10 to 60, but it did not work. Beyond 60, the servo motor does not respond at all.

Please help me figure out a way to increase the speed of the servo motor.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain in words what each line of the for loop is doing?  This seems to be a general Python question.

Comment: So, basically the servo motor rotates between 2 end points i.e up and down (variables). To change its position I need to give different PWM durations. So, 545 to 145 are those pwm durations for which I get different servo motor positions. The code works , but the servo motor rotates very slowly. Youtube videos show the same motor rotating very quickly

Comment: How many different PWM positions are you giving and how quickly?

Comment: 420 pwm positions (i.e 565-145) and they are being applied at an interval of 0.001 seconds

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?  A servo moves to the commanded position.  There is no need to ask it to go to 420 intermediate positions.

Comment: Those intermediate positions are required because I want the transition to be smooth. Without using a for loop/going directly to those edges, results in sudden jerky motions. This might destabilize the structure on which the motor is supported. Thats why I am using a for loop.

Comment: It seems like you are between a rock and a hard place.  You decide how many intermediate steps are best for your application.